# Reduce database connections

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database-connection

I am currently making a small webpage for my server, where it shows some stats of the players who play on it. It works pretty good, but I was just wondering if I could reduce the amount of connections to the database. Currently, I have some JQuery code in the page which refreshes parts of it to show the latest data. Now, I've never used JQuery before, so I did it like this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#blocks").load("blocks.php<? if($usePlayer){echo("?player=" . $player);} ?>");
     $("#global_stats").load("globalstats.php<? if($usePlayer){echo("?player=" . $player);} ?>");
     $("#top_entities").load("entities.php<? if($usePlayer){echo("?player=" . $player);} ?>");
   var blockRefresh = setInterval(function() {
      $("#blocks").load("blocks.php<? if($usePlayer){echo("?player=" . $player);} ?>");
   }, 5000);
   var globalStatsRefresh = setInterval(function() {
       $("#global_stats").load("globalstats.php<? if($usePlayer){echo("?player=" . $player);} ?>");
   }, 30000);

   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

The thing is, all three parts of the page I am reloading need a MySQL database connection. Currently, I am including db.php on every page, but that seems rather inefficient. What would be a good way to do this instead?

Oh, the page can be seen here: http://mc.centrility.nl/stats/

Comment: Load all data with only one call and return it from the server as JSON. Then devide up the JSON data to fill your different areas.

Comment: djot , how would I combine that with the reloading of the data?

Comment: rather than using load, you would use $.ajax then use the response to find the data thena ppend it to the divs!

Comment: I think djot is suggesting that you send the data needed for #global_stats and #blocks using the same php file. Then you will only need one Interval and one Db connection. Additionally, you might consider using [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), opening only one Db connection for all the updates and only sending the data when a change has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, more detailed:

Make only one connection to your server all.php. As RoryPickering said, use $.ajax for this.

On server side, only all.php is called once.

Set db connections to persistent there, so you only have to connect to the database once.

I doubt that you can fetch all data with only one query, so I guess you will have to query the database more than once.

Get all data and transform it to JSON format, which you return to the client.

On client side, split the JSON data to your according areas/needed sub data.

Comment: I definitely will give this a try. Any hints/tricks/examples?